# SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's NLSSORT function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to convert a Oracle query that uses a DB-Specific function NLSSORT in it's order by clause.

```
order by NLSSORT(col, 'NLS_SORT=GENERIC_M')
```

I would like to do the same functionality in SQL Server (2008). I am having trouble finding the equivalent logic to do this.

Comment: The equivalent is likely as simple as `ORDER BY col`. SQL Server performs ordering according to the column's collation by default, which is already equivalent to something like `GENERIC_M` unless you've explicitly set it to a binary collation. You may need to take a closer look at why there's an explicit `NLSSORT` here, as in, why the default `ORDER BY` doesn't yield satisfactory results on the Oracle end.

Comment: You would be better off explaining what the function does than relying on someone who knows both it and SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is likely as simple as `ORDER BY col`. SQL Server performs ordering according to the column's collation by default, which is already equivalent to something like GENERIC_M unless you've explicitly set it to a binary collation. You may need to take a closer look at why there's an explicit NLSSORT here, as in, why the default ORDER BY doesn't yield satisfactory results on the Oracle end.

If you need to sort by a collation other than the column's collation, use [COLLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver16#a-specifying-collation-during-a-select), eg

```
CREATE TABLE Locations
(Place varchar(15) NOT NULL);
GO
INSERT Locations(Place) VALUES ('Chiapas'),('Colima')
                             , ('Cinco Rios'), ('California');
GO
--Apply an typical collation
SELECT Place FROM Locations
ORDER BY Place
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS ASC;
GO
-- Apply a Spanish collation
SELECT Place FROM Locations
ORDER BY Place
COLLATE Traditional_Spanish_ci_ai ASC;
GO
```